# mutate in useSWR hook not updating the DOM

Tags: javascript, next.js, swr

It's a next.js app and I populate the data using a `useSWR` hook.

```
const { data, error } = useSWR('/api/digest', fetcher, {
    revalidateOnFocus: false,
})
```

The issue is that the DOM doesn't get updated as expected after the `mutate()` line below. But if I hard code the data as `updatedData` and pass it as the arg for the mutate it works normally. The fact is that `data` and the `updatedData` are the same. See comments below.

Edit: If I click on any Navbar `<Link/>` it gets updated.

Any clues of what is happening?

```
const handleAddRowClick = async () => {

    const newRow = { category: selectedCategory, entity: selectedEntity }
    data.subscription[selectedCategory].push(selectedEntity);

    console.log(data); // This data is equal to updatedData
    
    const updatedData = {
        "subscription": {
            "materialFact": [
                "Boeing"
            ],
            "headlines": [
                "thejournal",
                "onemagazine" // ***This is the value added.
            ]
        }
    }
    // mutate('/api/digest', data, false) // This does not works.
    mutate('/api/digest', updatedData , false) // It works.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that the `data` property you use in `handleAddRowClick` is the same that you get from `useSWR`. Now, if you update some deeply nested object in `data`, it doesn't change the data reference. It still points to the old object. So, if you pass it again to `mutate`, for mutate, the object is still the same and hence, it won't trigger a re-render.

I would recommend that you do something like the following to derive `updatedData` from `data` and then pass it to the `mutate` function.

```js
const handleAddRowClick = async () => {
    const updatedData = {
        ...data,
        subscription: {
            ...data.subscription,
            [selectedCategory]: [
                ...data.subscription[selectedCategory],
                selectedEntity,
            ]
        }
    }

    mutate('/api/digest', updatedData , false);
}
```

On a side note, you can also use something like [immer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/immer) to simplify copying the state.

Comment: I thought this as well, but SWR uses [deep comparison](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/advanced/performance) using  [dequal](https://github.com/lukeed/dequal). Shouldn't this work then? I'm sure that I miss something

Comment: It worked! Thank you. But the object isn't deeply nested. above `subscription` there's just one level. Maybe what you said happens regardless of the object depth? Trying to better understand what happened but again thank you!!!

Comment: It doesn't matter the level of depth you have in your object, it still needs a different reference.